# How to archive my project in Xcode without a developer's certificate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5, archive

I'm trying to archive my iOS project with Xcode 4.5.2. I do not have a developer's certificate yet (or, in other words, I haven't paid Apple their $99 fee.) When I go to Product -> Archive, it is grayed out. After doing a quick search it turns out that I need to add a physical device to use that feature (which would be kinda strange requirement, but OK.) Since I don't have a dev cert I can't add a device. So how can archive my project in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a developer profile to do the archiving. It will be grayed out if you have selected simulator as well. Try selecting iOS device and then do the archive. It will ask you to select a profile at that time. So I would recommend you to get one.

You do not need to connect a physical device to Xcode to do the archiving. You can just select iOS device option and do this.

Check the [documentation here to know more about this.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/distributing_ios_apps.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I guess I was misunderstanding the meaning of the word "archive." If I want to archive the xcode project for a backup purpose, is there such an option?

Comment: You have to compress the entire project and keep it somewhere for backing it up. There are no other ways. Mostly people use SVN so that they dont have to worry about this.

Comment: OK. I see. I was just hoping that by having a built-in option, it would delete all the cache files, etc. to minimize the size of the resulting archive.